# How can I pass a value service to a component?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to turn a directive into a component.

I have a value service ('path') defined on the app, which returns a path that was used to create the template url. With the directive it could be injected into the function and then used to create the template url like this:

```
.directive('myCustomer', [ 'path', function(path) {
  return {
    templateUrl: path + '/customer.html'
  };
}]);
```

How can I pass 'path' to a component, where I have an object instead of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.component('myCustomer',  {
    template: `<div ng-include="$ctrl.templateUrl"></div>`,
    controller: ['path', function(path) {
        this.templateUrl = path + '/customer.html'
    }] 
});
```

**Note:** As components use isolate scope, appropriate bindings need to be added to both the component and the HTML where it is instantiated.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Answer (score 0):

Use component bindings to consume the value.
Refer to docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: The values passed as bindings will be available on the controller, but how do I pass them to templateUrl?

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
template: '<div ng-include="$ctrl.templateUrl">'
```

store the value in templateUrl using component binding.